# Simulaneous changes to objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in the process of developing an app that manages the inventory in a shop. I assume that there could be potentially more than one user working with the app and therefore a scenario where both could reserver for checkout the same item (but for two different recipients is a likely one.

Are there any gems that or techniques someone could recommend that could help with this?

When the users create a new order they get the list of objects that are not reserved (this is a rental shop) but if one leaves the form open for a bit, without making the reservation, someone else still sees the item as available.

Can anyone offer advice about this? Hope the question is not too vague.

Is callbacks the way to go, by creating a before_save validation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) where you can schedule a job to be run at certain time, in this case, after a certain timeout.
You can then schedule a job which removes the reservation status on an item. If the user is successful in reserving the item, the delayed job needs to be deleted.
To delete the item from this activerecord table, you can find it based on the table attributes specified [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details).